# Java / Spring : Add multiple soap headers to getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive

Tags: java, soap, header

I am new to Java and following this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ to call Soap (.net asmx) service from Java Api. When I try to add headers into Soap Request it returns Java Null Pointer exception. If I don't supply HeaderComposingCallback then it is able to call the service.

Call web service:

```
ValidateResponse response = (ValidateResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "http://somewhere.com/service.asmx",
                    request, new HeaderComposingCallback());
```

Implementing WebServiceMessageCallback:

```
public class HeaderComposingCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

private PrincipalIdentity prinIdentity;
private ProductIdentity prodIdentity;

public HeaderComposingCallback() {

}

@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {

    ((SoapMessage) message).setSoapAction("Validate");
    SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader();

    try {

        prinIdentity.setRequestorId("value");
        ..

        prodIdentity.setAppId("value");
        ..

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PrincipalIdentity.class, ProductIdentityHeader.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(prinIdentity, soapHeader.getResult());
        marshaller.marshal(prodIdentity, soapHeader.getResult());

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new IOException("error while marshalling.");
    }
}
```

}